# How to remove list of tables (or figure, acronyms) in the abstract or acknowledgements?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am writing my thesis by using LaTex, and I have the list as below;

- List of tables
- List of acronyms
- Acknowledgements
- Abstract

Howerver, I do not know in the acknowledgements or abstract in the top of page has "list of acronyms". I would like to remove it in the abstract. Please see my figure.
Please give me your idea.
Thanks a lot

[image]

Herein the main code

```
\documentclass[11pt,makeidx,twoside]{phdthesis}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{captionhack}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{makeidx}     % to create make automatically an index
\makeindex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}


\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{}

\newcommand{\footnoteremember}[2]{
  \footnote{#2}
  \newcounter{#1}
  \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}
} \newcommand{\footnoterecall}[1]{
  \footnotemark[\value{#1}]
}


%%% Path to the directory containing the graphics and figures
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}


%%% General page formatting
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.01}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.99}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.99}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.99}

\newenvironment{Abstract}
{\begin{center}\textbf{Abstract}%

 \end{center} \small \it \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}}

%\pdfcompresslevel=3

\typeout{Dissertation}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\includeonly{title_page,acronyms,acknowledgements,abstract,chapter_1,chapter_2,chapter_3,chapter_4,chapter_5,Appendix1,Appendix2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Beginning of the document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\include{title_page}
\pagenumbering{roman}


%% create the table of contents
\cleardoublepage \lhead[]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\chead[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{}}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\include{acronyms}
%%  add the acknowledgements to the table of contents
\include{acknowledgements}
\include{abstract}

\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\publ}{}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\plainfootrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\it \thesection.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{
       \it \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\lhead[\thepage]{\fancyplain{\publ}{\rightmark}}
\chead[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\lfoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\rfoot[]{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapter_1} 
\end{document}
```

Herein the acronyms code

```
\chapter*{List of Acronyms}
\markboth{List of Acronyms}{}
\begin{acronym}[]

\acro{Acronyms}{Meaning} 
\acro{AMC}{Adaptive Modulation and Coding}

\end{acronym}
```

Comment: Without showing some code, it's hard to say.  How are you generating the headers?  Do you want the header to  show Acknowledgements and Abstract on those pages or nothing at all?  Please edit your question to show a minimal compilable document that shows the problem. [I've just been asked to write a minimal example. What is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: This is not a compilable example. It's a code fragment.

Comment: This is still a fragment.  And we can't compile anything that uses `\include` so replace those with dummy text that does what they do (I assume `\chapter*{...}`.

Comment: Also, what is the `documentclass` you are using? Please include that in, along with relevant packages to make the code compilable.

Comment: Dear @Troy and Alan, I added more details. Thanks

Comment: Did you actually read the link I posted, and my third comment? Also, where is `phdthesis.cls` from?

Comment: Dear @AlanMunn Im my template, we are using \include instead the \input. And `phdthesis.cls` is in `\documentclass[11pt,makeidx,twoside]{phdthesis}`

Comment: I think the problem in the list of acronyms. How do you think? Thanks

Comment: If Acknowledgements are an unnumbered chapter:`\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\markboth{}{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed a similar issue by adding:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

before the part where I don't want headers and footers.

And I added

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Where I wanted to appear...

Try adding the \pagestyle{empty} here:

```
\pagestyle{empty} %<------ HERE
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\include{acronyms}
%%  add the acknowledgements to the table of contents
\include{acknowledgements}
\include{abstract}
```

Comment: It works, well done
Thanks a lot @Alexandros :)